# How do I configure SemanticMerge as the merge tool in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, semantic-merge

Is there any way to configure SemanticMerge for use with Visual Studio 2017?
I've checked the [SemanticMerge documentation](https://users.semanticmerge.com/documentation/how-to-configure/semanticmerge-configuration-guide.shtml#HowtoconfigurewithVisualStudioCode) and they only describe configuration with Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if Semantic Merge is still installed in your Visual Studio?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodiceSoftware.SemanticMerge-CandVBNetawarediffandmergetool